# What's the node.js paradigm for socket stream conversation?

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream

I'm trying to implement a socket protocol and it is unclear to me how to proceed.  I have the socket as a Stream object, and I am able to write() data to it to send on the socket, and I know that the "readable" or "data" events can be used to receive data.  But this does not work well when the protocol involves a conversation in which one host is supposed to send a piece of data, wait for a response, and then send data again after the response.

In a block paradigm it would look like this:

```
send some data
wait for specific data reply
massage data and send it back
send additional data
```

As far as I can tell, node's Stream object does not have a read function that will asynchronously return with the number of bytes requested.  Otherwise, each wait could just put the remaining functionality in its own callback.

What is the node.js paradigm for this type of communication?

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is a Readable.read() but its not recommended (maybe you can't be sure of the size or it blocks, not sure.) You can keep track of state and on each data event add to a Buffer that you keep processing incrementally.  You can use readUInt32LE etc. on Buffer to read specific pieces of binary data if you need to do that (or you can convert to string if its textual data).  https://github.com/runvnc/metastream/blob/master/index.js

If you want to write it in your 'block paradigm', you could basically make some things a promise or async function and then

```
let specialReplyRes = null;

waitForSpecialReply = f => new Promise( res => specialReplyRes = res);

stream.on('data', (buff) => {
  if (buff.toString().indexOf('special')>=0) specialReplyRes(buff.toString());
});

// ...

async function proto() {
  stream.write(data);
  let reply = await waitForSpecialReply();
  const message = massage(reply);
  stream.write(message);
}
```

Where your waitForSpecialReply promise is stored and resolved after a certain message is received through your parsing.

Comment: Haven't really wrapped my head around promises yet... with regards to the state based approach, that's how I'm doing it on the server side where all I need to do is get a request and send a reply, but on the client side it's a bit more complicated since I have to send, receive, send and then receive, so I have to somehow synchronize the sending and receiving.